# Glossaries: emphasize first occurrence of every section

Tags: glossaries

I'm searching a way to emphasize the first occurrence of a glossary term in every section

```
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{webapp}{
    name=webapp,
    first={\underline{webapp}},
    description={description of the webapp}
}
```

If i use this in this way

```
\section{first}
\gls{webapp} \gls{webapp} \gls{webapp} \gls{webapp}

\section{second}
\gls{webapp} \gls{webapp} \gls{webapp} \gls{webapp}
```

Only the fist occurrence on the first section will be underlined, the other occurrence will not.

Is there a solution to make also the first occurrence of "webapp" on the second section be underlined?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you can just issue the command `\glsreset{webapp}` to reset the behavior when needed. If you want to reset the behavior for all glossary entries use `\glsresetall`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{webapp}{
    name=webapp,
    first={\underline{webapp}},
    description={description of the webapp}
}

\begin{document}

\section{frist}
\gls{webapp} \gls{webapp} \gls{webapp} \gls{webapp}

\section{second}
\glsreset{webapp}
\gls{webapp} \gls{webapp} \gls{webapp} \gls{webapp}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you don't want to insert that line manually each time you issue a `\section`, you can insert the following line in the preamble

```
\pretocmd{\section}{\glsresetall}{}{}
```

It requires `etoolbox` which is automatically loaded by `glossaries`.

For example, the following MWE produces the same result as the above one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{webapp}{
    name=webapp,
    first={\underline{webapp}},
    description={description of the webapp}
}

\pretocmd{\section}{\glsresetall}{}{}

\begin{document}

\section{first}
\gls{webapp} \gls{webapp} \gls{webapp} \gls{webapp}

\section{second}
\gls{webapp} \gls{webapp} \gls{webapp} \gls{webapp}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: @RikyTres Remember that you can accept the answer, if it solves your problem. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: Yep man! I've done it ;) I was just try it before accept it...